# How to get all node ids from same content type

Tags: 8, nodes

I am using Drupal 8 and I want to create related content, but the problem is that I can't figure it out, how I can get all node IDs(except current one) for a specific content type.

Comment: Why not use Views for this task?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic query that returns last 10 changed nodes (published) of type 'article'. Modify for your needs.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->condition('type', 'article')
  ->range(0, 10)
  ->sort('changed', 'DESC');
$nids = $query->execute();
```

Comment: I think you need to add in a condition to exclude current node id.